# Styling select dropdowns without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've used the jQuery plugin [Uniform.js](http://uniformjs.com) before and it works great.

The only issue I have is that it relies on jQuery. I'm working on a project that really doesn't need jQuery, and I'm reluctant to load an entire framework just for one plugin.

Does anyone know of another plugin that does what Uniform does but doesn't rely on any frameworks?

Comment: Currently, what is the size of your page (including all assets!) without a primed cache? I'm just curious.

Comment: 90kb hit....one time thanks to caching.....no hit to your server thanks to CDN loading.  Not worth the battle!

Comment: a css only solution maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you're not going to gain much by avoiding jQuery, and you're probably going to waste a lot of time even if you do find something that suits your needs. I mean, it's only 31KB (plus the size of the plugin).

Comment: At the moment I've been very careful about file sizes on this site, and I'm very reluctant to load in an entire framework for something so simple. It seems that people use jQuery without thinking these days. Sometimes it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: That's fine. I wish I had an actual answer for you, but, with the information you've given, it still seems to me like you may be prematurely optimizing. Ask yourself, "Can I really not spare 31K?"

Comment: Honestly, though, it's usually only one time, and then the client caches the library. To save some of your own bandwidth, you could link to Google's version of the jQuery library, which may actually speed up loading of your site (considering the fact that Google's servers are extremely fast).

Answer (score 2):

If you're set on not using jQuery, maybe have a look at [NiceForms](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/).

There are some demos on [this page](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/demo/v20/niceforms.html), and the script file is under 10kb when [packed](http://jscompress.com/).

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks, I may well end up using this.

Comment: Niceform [github page says (in 2014)](https://github.com/emblematiq/Niceforms#compatibility) "Important: In its current form, Niceforms is more than 3 years old and becoming more and more obsolete given the ever increasing browser support for CSS3 and other modern techniques. Use at your own risk!", and later on the same page "Niceforms is fully compatible with most modern browsers: IE7+, Firefox2+, Safari3+, Opera9+, Chrome0.3+, Mozilla1.5+, Camino1.6+". I'm confused